# Exporting data from PostgreSQL as CSV to S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, django, amazon-web-services

I have a general question regarding DRY. As you can see there are several parts such as `io.StringIO()`, `csv.writer`, `io.BytesIO` which are repeated. I now wonder if there is a better way, where I don't seem to `repeat` myself. Or is the way how I use it here a fair approach and not considered as DRY?

**What does your code do?**

With the code, I create two CSV-files in the buffer and directly upload them to an AWS S3 bucket. The data for these files are from my Postgres database. The framework I use is Django. That's why I am able to access the database with commands such as `Event.objects.filter`

**What does the rest of your program look like?**

That's basically all of the program. After the CSV-files are available on my bucket an AWS Lambda function proceeds with the data and a machine learning model.

**What Python version did you write this for?**

I use Python 3.

```
class Forecast:
    @classmethod
    def export_data_for_forecast(cls):
        s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=settings.ML_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.ML_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        )

        BUCKET_NAME = 'fbprophet'
        EVENT_DATA_OBJECT = 'event_data_test.csv'
        ORDER_DATA_OBJECT = 'orders_order_test.csv'

        events = Event.objects.filter(status=EventStatus.LIVE).prefetch_related(
            'orders'
        )

        # Prepare buffer for csv files
        event_data_buffer = io.StringIO()
        event_data_writer = csv.writer(event_data_buffer)
        event_data_writer.writerow(["Event PK", "Name", "Start date"])

        order_data_buffer = io.StringIO()
        order_data_writer = csv.writer(order_data_buffer)
        order_data_writer.writerow(["Event PK", "Created", "Total Gross"])

        active_events = filter(lambda event: not event.is_over, events)
        for event in active_events:
            event_data_writer.writerow([event.pk, event.name, event.start_date])

            for order in event.orders.all():
                order_data_writer.writerow(
                    [order.event.pk, order.created, order.total_gross]
                )

        # Prepare buffer and transform to binary
        event_data_buffer_to_binary = io.BytesIO(
            event_data_buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8')
        )
        order_data_buffer_to_binary = io.BytesIO(
            order_data_buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8')
        )

        # Upload to S3
        s3.upload_fileobj(event_data_buffer_to_binary, BUCKET_NAME, EVENT_DATA_OBJECT)
        s3.upload_fileobj(order_data_buffer_to_binary, BUCKET_NAME, ORDER_DATA_OBJECT)
```

Comment: What does your code do? What does the rest of your program look like? What Python version did you write this for? We need more information and more context before being able to review this. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I Mast thank you for your answer. I added the missing information. Hope that's better.

Comment: Good, better already. Can you please change your title to reflect what your code does as well? Keep the concerns for the body of the question, not the title. The language doesn't have to be in the title either, we have tags for that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code's straightforward enough at a glance, I wouldn't have worried
too much about the duplicate bits, especially since it's only double and
not multiple times for each part!  Overdoing abstraction can hurt readability too.  See below for some thoughts on how I'd approach this with that warning in mind.

---

First of I'd try and move some of the functionality out of the function.
The constants ... should be constants and not right in the middle of the
function body.  Plus, some of them look like constants, while some are
inline (`'orders'`).  I can't tell why the distinction is made here,
maybe there was a reason.

Also consider making all of this not a class method, but a regular one,
then you could for example start creating helper objects beforehand
(like the `s3` client) and/or pass in preconstructed ones, e.g. for
testing purposes (like with mock objects).

I'm not going to do these changes right here because you might have had
a reason for the `@classmethod`.

---

Instead, let's do a few different changes to make the flow a little bit
easier to comprehend for a reader not already familiar with the code
base:

- Moving construction and usage of an object closely together will let
  readers just continue reading while not having to jump up the block
  again to find out where a particular name was defined ... *unless*
  there are pressing reasons like failing early if no connection could
  be made (c.f. the `s3` client, though I'm guessing it doesn't actually
  establish a connection until the `upload_fileobj` call is made).
- Breaking out functionality into more functions (or even local helper
  functions, no one's stoppiing you from creating more abstractions.
  Alternatively, and I think that's better suited for this case, create
  a new class to wrap things together that belong together.  The hint
  for me here is `event_data_...` appearing with two suffixes and then
  `order_data_...` with the same suffixes.  That begs to be an object
  with two attributes.

E.g. like this:

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'fbprophet'
EVENT_DATA_OBJECT = 'event_data_test.csv'
ORDER_DATA_OBJECT = 'orders_order_test.csv'


class ForecastBuffer:
    def __init__(self, columns):
        # Prepare buffer for csv files
        self.buffer = io.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.buffer)
        self.writer.writerow(columns)

    def write_row(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow(row)

    def upload(self, s3, bucket_name, object_name):
        # Prepare buffer and transform to binary
        to_binary = io.BytesIO(self.buffer.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
        s3.upload_fileobj(to_binary, bucket_name, object_name)


class Forecast:
    @classmethod
    def export_data_for_forecast(cls):
        event_data = ForecastBuffer(["Event PK", "Name", "Start date"])
        order_data = ForecastBuffer(["Event PK", "Created", "Total Gross"])

        events = Event.objects.filter(status=EventStatus.LIVE).prefetch_related(
            'orders'
        )

        for event in filter(lambda event: not event.is_over, events):
            event_data.write_row([event.pk, event.name, event.start_date])

            for order in event.orders.all():
                order_data.write_row(
                    [order.event.pk, order.created, order.total_gross]
                )

        # Upload to S3
        s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=settings.ML_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.ML_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        )

        event_data.upload(s3, BUCKET_NAME, EVENT_DATA_OBJECT)
        order_data.upload(s3, BUCKET_NAME, ORDER_DATA_OBJECT)
```

Okay, so, the methods still a bit long in the middle.

One thing that came to my mind was that `order.event.pk` is probably the
same as `event.pk` itself, right?  Maybe check and simplify that.

Then, the `filter` call with the `lambda` feels a bit weird to me, could
that perhaps already be filtered out in the `Event.objects.filter...`
chain above it?

You could also move one last bit to make things clearer:  Don't expose
the "raw" `writerow` call, instead just feed objects to the buffers:

```
        for event in filter(lambda event: not event.is_over, events):
            event_data.write(event)

            for order in event.orders.all():
                order_data.write(order)
```

However, that would require to have either a method on the object being
written that specifies the serialisation output (well, which values to
select for the rows), or the same information on the `ForecastBuffer`
object (you could pass in a function that formats an object for CSV).
Depends entirely on the rest of the code if that's worth it / feasible
at all.

---

Btw. I just saw that `itertools` has a complement to `filter` called
[`filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) (arguably that could be a better name, `keep` comes to my
mind):

```
        # from itertools import filterfalse

        for event in filterfalse(Event.is_over, events):
            event_data.write(event)
```

Assuming that you can get the unbound method `Event.is_over` that way.

---

Coming back to that `@classmethod`, the method here is difficult to test
due to the global variables.  Depending on how it's called it might be
worth to make `events` a parameter so that the functionality of *this
method* is simply: format to CSV and upload.  Same goes for `settings` -
the `s3` client most definitely should be passed in so this function
doesn't have to deal with configuration on top of formatting and
uploading.

Actually that's still two things, but it's short enough that that's
probably okay, splitting the formatting into another method might also
be worth it actually:

```
class Forecast:
    @classmethod
    def format_data_for_forecast(cls, events):
        event_data = ForecastBuffer(["Event PK", "Name", "Start date"])
        order_data = ForecastBuffer(["Event PK", "Created", "Total Gross"])

        for event in filterfalse(Event.is_over, events):
            event_data.write(event)

            for order in event.orders.all():
                order_data.write(order)

        return event_data, order_data

    @classmethod
    def export_data_for_forecast(cls):
        events = Event.objects.filter(status=EventStatus.LIVE).prefetch_related(
            'orders'
        )

        event_data, order_data = cls.format_data_for_forecast(events)

        # Upload to S3
        s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id=settings.ML_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.ML_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        )

        event_data.upload(s3, BUCKET_NAME, EVENT_DATA_OBJECT)
        order_data.upload(s3, BUCKET_NAME, ORDER_DATA_OBJECT)
```

Comment: Great review and extremely helpful. Thank you @ferada